# Multiple values for the same variable in mod rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^animals$ ?filter=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^plants$ ?filter=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tech$ ?filter=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^social ?filter=$1 [L]
```

Is there a way to combine these into 1 rule? as the list is actually larger than that and it's the same rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be combined into one rule using regex `OR`:

```
RewriteRule ^(animals|plants|tech|social)/?$ ?filter=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```